# Circuit to detect presence or absense of current

Tags: current-measurement

I'm trying to come up with a bad-bulb detector for a circuit that will control the turn signals and brake lights in a car or truck. I'm defining "bad bulb" here as an open circuit, which is what typically happens when a light dies in a vehicle.

The allowable current range per output is pretty large: 100mA to 10A. This will allow the installer to use a single LED bulb on each output or several old-fashioned incandescents in parallel. In order for the MCU to detect a bad bulb, it only needs to know that current flowed or didn't flow, not necessarily how much.

Ideally, the circuit will have an extremely low part count and very inexpensive components (but still work in an automotive environment). This is mostly because the circuit will need to be duplicated several times on the PCB, so any excess will grow the size of the PCB and the budget. And the budget for this project is extremely small.

Here's one idea I've come up with so far using only passive components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxxtQE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When M1 is turned on, C1 charges up and power is available to the bulb. When M1 is turned off, one of two things may happen:

1. If the bulb was good, C1 will supply additional current to the bulb for a very short amount of time. NODE1 will very quickly drop to zero volts, which will cause NODE2 to also drop off quickly. If the GPIO pin samples NODE2 a few milliseconds after M1 was turned off, it should see a digital low signal. A low signal indicates the bulb is good.
2. If the bulb was bad, the only load to drain C1 will be the resistor divider R1 and R2. But those resistors are large, so the voltage across C1 will stay higher longer. If GPIO samples NODE2 a few milliseconds after M1 is turned off, it should see a digital high. A high signal indicates the bulb is bad.

Everything outside the dotted box is already committed in the schematic, so I'm just adding two resistors, two capacitors, and two diodes per output (D1 and D2 are just to protect the MCU from load dumps). These parts might add up to 25 cents per output, which is great. This is an adequate solution, albeit untested outside of simulation so far.

I'm hoping to get some ideas for clever ways to do this using even less components or for making it more robust. I would also appreciate critiques on the circuit I've presented above.

Comment: "If the bulb was bad, ... the voltage across C1 will stay higher longer." - how will you know that it was longer? IOW how do you know the _actual_ time when M1 turned off?

Comment: Did you consider about using Hall sensors instead?

Comment: To keep it simple, I think maybe a current sense diode with a pnp BE junction spanning the current sense diode. If possible, mount the transistor and diode in intimate physical contact for thermal tracking. If there is enough current to forward bias the diode, it should also forward bias the BE junction. Put a resistor between collector and ground. Might be workable, might not. Might need a lot of tuning to get it right.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, the schematic doesn't show it, but the MOSFET driver is ultimately controlled by the MCU. The driver's inputs (turn signal and brake) are interpreted by the MCU, which in turn drives the MOSFETs.

Comment: @mkeith, very interesting idea. Will have to simulate that and see what I come up with.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, yes, I did look at Hall effect sensors. I didn't find anything in the price range I was looking for - at least, as compared to the cost of a few passive components.

Comment: innovative design, that would work with old sytle bulbs or single LED's, however you may want to consider what will happen if a string of series LED's is used as the "bulb" as is common in 12V electronics (I'm assuming this is 12V as you mentioned automotive work). If this is not a problem you may also want to buffer your output through a comparitor with a low threshold refererance voltage, to ensure signal integraty.

Comment: @LordNibbler, valid point. I did actually simulate 3 LEDs plus a resistor in series as a load. The voltage drops off enough for the concept to work, although it is a noticeably different curve than a purely resistive load. I won't know for sure until I try it on a real automotive LED bulb though.

Comment: I see some potential problems with your design: 1. LEDs fail to short circuit, incandescents fail to open circuit. How do you want to differentiate between failed LEDs and good incandescents? 2. how do you want to detect failed bulb during driving? Your circuit could detect failure only when you switch bulb off. Bad bulb should be detected before departure.

Comment: @Chupacabras, good points. 1. All the automotive bulbs I've ever replaced failed open (incandescent and LED), but I can definitely see the possibility of one failing closed. That will require more design thought. I may just go with in-line fuses.  2. I think detecting the bad bulb after the light turns off is ok. The turn signals and brake are typically activated frequently and for short periods of time, so the MCU will know after the first use and report to the driver. That's not ideal (as you said, ideal would be to report before departure), but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider an 'old school' method - using a reed switch with several turns of wire wrapped around it. When current flows through the wire the magnetic field closes the switch.

[image]

The switches do come as spdt types or you can reverse the 'logic' with a simple transistor inverter or logic gate.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking about detecting the magnetic field near an inductor, but I hadn't considered putting an inductor around a reed switch.

Comment: @DanLaks Basic principles never change, just the technology. Its worth experimenting with one.

Answer (score 0):

You will need current sense resistor you will put between bulb and M1 MOSFET.
Then you will monitor voltage across this sense resistor.
If M1 is on and this voltage is lower or higher than some threshold then that bulb is faulty.

Comment: Did you read the question or just the title?

Comment: @pipe, yes I did. That's why I suggested to use current sense resistor.

Comment: It would be much simpler to put a sense resistor between LED bulb and GND. Then using a multiplexer for many of them and comparator /or/ ADC. This is also the method, used in many ECUs.

Comment: @Chupacabras, thank you, but I don't think a traditional current sense shunt resistor is a good solution to my question. At a minimum, I'd need to add voltage dividers and op amps to bring the voltages down to logic level and measure the voltage difference. The voltage drop would be small, which means I'd need very high precision resistors to accurately read the voltage difference, which are costly. The op amps would come in IC packages which will probably take up more space on the PCB. Higher cost and more board space was the opposite of what I was looking for.

Comment: @Dan Laks, you do NOT need high precision resistors because you just need to detect presence of current. And you do NOT need to bring voltages down to logic level if you will use low side measuring (as suggested Marko Buršič). That is the simplest (and the most robust) way to detect current.

Comment: @Chupacabras Unfortunately, as this is an automotive application, the ground path returns through the vehicle chassis. I cannot use a low side shunt. And high precision resistors would be necessary for a high side measurement (as you originally suggested). To allow for the 100mA to 10A requirement, I would need to choose a small current shunt resistor to minimize I^2R losses. Therefore, the voltage drop across the resistor would be very small if 100mA bulbs are used. High precision resistors (as well as a high precision ADC) would be necessary to detect the current.

Comment: @Dan, imagine you will use 0.005Ω 5%. It will dissipate 0.5W at 10A current and with 0.05V voltage drop. That is reasonable. At 100mA, there will be 0.5mV drop. And use high-side current monitor (like ZXCT1023, this is just random example), it works from 0V to 20V, and Vout=50*Vsense. So Vout would be between 25mV and 2.5V. You do NOT need precise ADC, just simple comparators. For levels you consider healthy. Like above 20mV and below 2.6V, and that will be simple digital input to your MCU to signal presence of current.

Comment: @Chupacabras, yes, you can replace high precision resistors with an IC package that costs over a dollar. In my question, I was looking for other clever circuits that are low part count and very low cost - akin to using just a few passive components that add up to a couple of nickels.

Answer (score 0):

M1 the P channel Drive mosfet does have on resistance so you already have a sense resistor .It will be "Accurate " to about 30% which for this job is fine .This is not a  new method .Some texts refer to this as channel resistance sensing .You need a highside comparetor which is not rare or expensive .I have implemented such a comparetor with discrete components 2 decades ago for an indicator lamp application where accuracy was not important .This scheme has the bonus of being able to add overcurrent protection for M1 which the attractively simple reed switch does not .